# if canonical mode is not set, nonblocking read fails?

Tags: c, stdin, nonblocking, canonical-link

Below code is an example of nonblocking read of `terminal` IO, however when I type a character on the console, it doesn't immediately print it out. Perpaps you will say I should priviously set `stty -icanon`, so canonical mode is disabled, that indeed works, but I think even though I don't disable `stty icanon`, nonblocking read of terminal is `character-oriented`, `cannonical` mode just wakes up the blocking process, but my process is not blocking, if we type a character, then the fd is readable, so it should immediately print the character out.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MSG_TRY "try again\n"

int main(void)
{
 char buf[10];
 int fd, n;
 fd = open("/dev/tty", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK);
 if(fd<0) {
    perror("open /dev/tty");
    exit(1);
 }
 tryagain:
   n = read(fd, buf, 10);
   if (n < 0) {
       if (errno == EAGAIN) {
            sleep(1);
            write(STDOUT_FILENO, MSG_TRY, strlen(MSG_TRY));
            goto tryagain;
       }    
    perror("read /dev/tty");
    exit(1);
   }
 write(STDOUT_FILENO, buf, n);
 close(fd);
 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

O as I have understood it, using the O_NONBLOCK flag while open, just tells open not to wait for a modem to become ready, if you for example try to open a terminal.

Found this source very helpful. http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Serial_Programming/termios#Opening.2FClosing_a_Serial_Device

I was doing some work with tty(RS232 port) devices today. 
http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Terminal-Modes.html#Terminal-Modes

How do you know if the terminal is canonical or raw? If i understand you correctly, you say you have set the terminal non canonical(raw) but it later changes back. Is this correct?
In that case where in your code have you set the device non canonical?

If you want raw mode, there is a function called cfmakeraw().
And dont forget to set your attributes with tcsetattr().
for example
const struct termios yourtermios
    yourtermios.c_cc[VTIME]=0;
    yourtermios.c_cc[VMIN]=1;
Or whatever value you see fit.

Here is a great source of information regarding canonical or not.
http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Canonical-or-Not.html#Canonical-or-Not

Answer (score 0):

If you want a function that takes a single unbuffered character here is a function I have written myself. It will read a single character(which is one key stroke most of the time) without waiting for the user to press the enter key.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <errno.h>

int ugetc(char *c)
{
    if(c == NULL) return EINVAL;

    struct termios term;

        //Get the current terminal settings so that only
        //the settings we want to change are changed
    if(tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &term) == -1) return errno;

        //Save the original terminal settings
    unsigned int c_lflag = term.c_lflag;
    unsigned int vmin = term.c_cc[VMIN];
    unsigned int vtime = term.c_cc[VTIME];

        //If line buffering is turned on then turn if off
    if(term.c_lflag & ICANON) term.c_lflag ^= ICANON;

        //Make sure that read() will wait for a single character
    term.c_cc[VMIN] = 1;
    term.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;

        //Apply the changed settings
    if(tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &term) == -1) return errno;

        //Verify that changes were made properly see "man tcgetattr" for more details
    if(tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &term) == -1) return errno;

        //Verify that changes were made properly see "man tcgetattr" for more details
    if
    (
        term.c_lflag & ICANON
        || term.c_cc[VMIN] != 1
        || term.c_cc[VTIME] != 0
    )
        //The value returned can be change to any valid errno macro
    return ECANCELED;

       //Save the read() return value for later processing
    int ret = read(STDIN_FILENO, c, 1);

        //Restore the old settings saved from earlier
    term.c_lflag = c_lflag;
    term.c_cc[VMIN] = vmin;
    term.c_cc[VTIME] = vtime;

        //Apply the restored settings
    if(tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &term) == -1) return errno;

        //Verify the changes were successful see "man tcgetattr" for more details
        //NOTE: If tcgetattr() fails to restore the original settings the terminal
        //will stay unbuffered
    if(tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &term) == -1) return errno;

        //Verify the changes were successful see "man tcgetattr" for more details
    if
    (
        term.c_lflag != term.c_lflag
        || term.c_cc[VMIN] != vmin
        || term.c_cc[VTIME] != vtime
    )
    return ECANCELED;

        //If a read error occured return errno
        //NOTE: If an error occurs we want to restore the old
        //settings anyway so we save the return value and check
        //it after the old settings have been restored

    if(ret == -1) return errno;

    return 0;
}
```

The function has not been extensively tested yet so you should test it yourself.